# Database SQL design

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql, database-design

I'm making a React app, and now I need to store `IBAN number, bank_name, bank_location etc...` for every user, and every user can have only 1 bank.

Currently I have one table that describe a User,

```
User(uid, name, lastname, bio, url_img, ..)
```

and now that I have to add new information do you think that is a good idea to create a new table for bank information or is better to put the new info in the User table?

Idea 1:

```
User (  uid
      , name
      , lastname
      , bio
      , url_img
      , IBAN_number
      , bank_name
      , bank_location
      )
```

Idea2:

```
User (uid, name, lastname, bio, url_img)

Bank_user_info(
       id
     , uid_user
     , IBAN_number
     , bank_name
     , bank_location
     )
```

is the idea 2 a good idea even a user will have maximum only just one bank_user_info row???

Comment: It is a matter of taste, but i prefer the second idea, cause each table will "hold" it's own domain.

Comment: The IBAN number is unique to each bank.  One field you're missing is the employee bank account number.  The bank ID and bank account number go in the User row.  The bank information goes in a Bank row.  There are usually only a few banks in town, but many employees.

Answer (score 1):

First case leads to logical errors, essentially  a `user` can not exist without a `bank`. Given that a single bank can have may clients, you are likely to keep redundantly repeating banking info and eventually resulting in contradicting information. Redundancy leads to contradiction, sooner or later.

In the second case `user` is independent, but (logically) `bank` does not exist without a `user`, and same redundant banking info problem as in the first case.

So, I would recommend

```
-- only attributes relevant to a user
--
user {USER_ID, ...}
  PK {USER_ID}

-- only attributes relevant to a bank
--
bank {BANK_ID, ...}
  PK {BANK_ID}


-- User banking detail (only one bank per user)
--
user_bank {USER_ID, BANK_ID, ACCOUNT_NO, ... }
       PK {USER_ID}
       AK {BANK_ID, ACCOUNT_NO}

FK1 {USER_ID} REFERENCES user {USER_ID}
FK2 {BANK_ID} REFERENCES bank {BANK_ID}
```

And if a user can bank with *more than one* bank:

```
user_bank {USER_ID, BANK_ID, ACCOUNT_NO, ... }
       PK {USER_ID, BANK_ID}
       AK {BANK_ID, ACCOUNT_NO}

FK1 {USER_ID} REFERENCES user {USER_ID}
FK2 {BANK_ID} REFERENCES bank {BANK_ID}
```

Notes:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 0):

With the bank table holding info about user id, the two table would have to be equal size, so two tables would be pointless. Since 1 bank will (in the real world) have more than 1 user, disk space will be saved by using a separate table for the bank info, without losing any data. This is the basic idea of a relational database.

Reconsider the fields you have proposed for your tables. The user table should have the unique info about each user, plus an id to identify their bank. The bank info table will contain that same id, and whatever else is unique to each bank.

Now that disk space is cheaper, you might consider putting everything in one table, if it isn't too unwieldy. But...suppose a bank has 1,000,000 customers and then changes its name. Would you rather update 1,000,000 rows in one giant table, or 1 row in the bank info table?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood my situation, the user will enter the info himself (IBAN, location_delete etc ...) using a form and I will not enter the available banks in advance etc ... so there will be little data in common. Because each user will enter their bank details which I will then use to make monthly transfers.

Comment: The size of your data set will determine whether you gain anything from having two tables. If there really is a 1:1 relationship between two pieces of data, then putting them into two tables would be a small decrease in performance (longer queries, more chance for errors, etc).

Comment: The problem with 1:1 is that most of then are actually not. This one is falls into this case. I'll grant the rule that a user can have only 1 bank, but a 1:1 also means a bank can have only 1 user.  To enforce 1:1 both your ideas require a unique constraint on IBAN_number.  If a customer is restricted to 1 bank then you have a 1:M relationship.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627896/7619059) explains when to use a new table or a new column. In your case, IBAN number can be an attribute of the User table, however other columns should be a part of the Bank entity. This prevents the replication of bank information (name, location) for each user. So the tables can be like:

User(uid, name, lastname, bio, url_img, IBAN, bank_id)
Bank(id, bank_name, bank_location)

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood my situation, the user will enter the info himself (IBAN, location_delete etc ...) using a form and I will not enter the available banks in advance etc ... so there will be little data in common. Because each user will enter their bank details which I will then use to make monthly transfers.